# Changing URL format in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change this  format

```
 http://mysite.tld/go.php?id=20
```

to

```
 http://mysite.tld/20
```

How can I achieve this with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: until now nothing work for me :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /go\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ go.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in previous answers, the usual way is to use [Apache's Rewrite Engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) via the .htaccess file.

#### If you're looking for a PHP specific solution:

1. Redirect all incoming requests to a single PHP page.
2. On this page, firstly retrieve the URL entered using the pre-defined [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array, excluding the base URL. (`$_SERVER["HTTPS"]`,`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`,`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`)
3. Once you have this, split up the URL into key and value pairs using the appropriate [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Regular_expression). (`'@/@'`)
4. Map the keys to keys of an array that stores page references.
5. Redirect to this page with POST or GET parameters of the values.